# Magento Global Messages not displaying site wide

Tags: magento-1.9

I have noticed that my site appears to no longer display any sort of global messages anymore.

I first noticed that there was no message being displayed if i entered the wrong password when logging in, but then realised that none of the messages are displaying anywhere.

As far as i can tell my templates haven't changed and still include the following line which is what is supposed to display the message

```
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml() ?>
```

Sample login page: `http://www.diegocordero.com.au/magento/customer/account/login/`

Thanks

Comment: Can anyone help? i'm totally at a loss here :(

Answer (score 1):

just in case it can help, I had a similar issue just now, the company I work for has many instances of their Magento website (a dev, a uat, a prod and our local devs) and for some reason I couldnt get any messages to come up on UAT while on all other instances, with the exact same code, it was working!

It turns out the problem was with my cookies! I just opened the site in a different browser and the messages were showing... I guess its worth trying to clear your cookies because it could be the issue, in my case it was!

Answer (score 0):

Two things have to check in code:

**This file:** app/design/frontend/**YOUR_THEME**/template/page/3columns.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?> //Must be added.
```

**This file:** app/design/frontend/**YOUR_THEME**/layout/page.xml

```
<block type="core/messages" name="global_messages" as="global_messages"/> //Must be added.
```

Comment: Hi Akhil,
Thanks for the suggestion. I've checked both these template files and they both contain the gobal messages codes. I'm not sure where else to look, any ideas?